# How to script CronTab

Tags: javascript, php, cron

I have a feature of sending emails with attachments and pre-defined texts, everything is working only now there has been a need to schedule a shot for these emails.

I found a script in JS that generates the command line for Cron:
[CLICK HERE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIKn7.png)

Is there any way to do this directly through PHP?

I thought of implementing it as follows:

Save the fields: minutes, hors, days, weeks, months in the database then I make a script that reads the records from the database and returns me which emails I should send.

In CPainel I would create a task by calling my script every 1 minute this script would return the records to be sent.

*I would like to leave a listing for the user to be able to edit and delete cron records*

Is this the best way?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create cron using cpanel's cron job. You can set the time in cron job and just name the url there for what you want to cron.

Comment: The best way would be to set script execution every 1 minute?